# ld: library not found for -lSystem trying to compile telldus sources

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I have this error:ld: library not found for -lSystem. I read some pother post but I did not find any solution. I tried to re-install xcode but it did not work.

I try to compile telldus-core for Big Sur on a M1 Mac. https://github.com/telldus/telldus/tree/master/telldus-core

I get some errors using cmake :

```
You are compiling sources from trunk.  Don't do that!
```

The install doc speak about setting up this flag (-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr), but I don't know very well cmake and makefiles. So I don't know if this is the real issue or not.

Here is the full log:

```
 Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
1
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
1
ld: library not found for -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You error message is `You are compiling sources from trunk.  Don't do that!`. Content of `CMakeError.log` is absolutely unrelated to that problem. Since that error message is part of `CMakeLists.txt`, then about its meaning ask the project's developers.

Comment: ok, I'm gonna edit and remove that. Thanks!

Comment: Eh? You have removed from the question post the **actual** error message. Content of `CMakeError.log` is **meaningless** without the actual error message. (And this content is meaningless in case of most errors).